# SQL left join where the joined table only displays the row column with lowest figure

Tags: sql

My current join with 3 tables works.  The 2nd table contains numbers, which are prices example: 800.  It contains several prices for the same item and I only want to display the lowest found related to the customers datatabase .  So I want to join the 2nd table on the condition that it only displays the row with the lowest number ONLY no others rows. I need some advice please thanks

The Table/column that contains the price is called "item.amount"  and the table is called "item".

```
$sql = "SELECT
customers.id, customers.name,
item.id, item.amount, fav.id

FROM customers

LEFT JOIN item   ON customers.id = item.id 
LEFT JOIN fav    ON customers.id = fav.id ";
```

Comment: Please don't tag multiple different RDBMS. Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. I have removed these tags and added the generic [tag:sql] tag.

Comment: Sample data and expected results (not images of these) along with you tagging the correct RDBMS will also greatly help us help you.

Comment: You still need to [edit] your question though, @greenman.

Comment: We can't help you if we don't know your data, expected results, or your RDBMS, @greenman , like I mentioned a couple of comments ago. You need to [edit] your question. Help us help you.

Comment: let me see  I think i have found the solution

Comment: Okay  will try and present it as you have requested. thank you

Comment: It seems odd that all 3 tables are joined on id. How are the tables related? You must post sample data and expected results.

Comment: The tables are related and joined by ID, as they all contain the same ID which I purposed for the reason of the relationship.

Comment: I am a newbie This is where I learnt about joinging tables using related IDs ```   https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp  ```   and also how tojoin 3 tables is on this link   ``` https://learnsql.com/blog/how-to-left-join-multiple-tables/```

Comment: You can relate by any thing the tables colums have in common it does not have to be IDs

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution using MIN(Point) MinPoint. This example explains and can be used with LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT tbl.*
FROM TableName tbl
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT Id, MIN(Point) MinPoint
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY Id
  ) tbl1
  ON tbl1.id = tbl.id
WHERE tbl1.MinPoint = tbl.Point
```